# Exclude Module from Magento Compilation

Tags: compiler

Is there any way to exclude some extensions/modules from magento compilation ?

Because some extensions create issues with magento compilation like uRapidFlow .

Comment: Magento's compilation mode is deprecated. For a better alternative, have a look at: http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-class-path-cache.html

Answer (score 1):

No afaik there is not. You can compile all the modules or none.

But if you ask me, instead of compiling magento you should turn on `realpath_cache_size` and `realpath_cache_ttl` in your `php.ini`.

I'm not sure what size is good, but caching the path, where PHP finds your file speeds magento up and solves the problem with "finding" files.

http://www.activo.com/2-php-directives-to-boost-your-magento-performance/

Comment: I am already using these with following values - realpath_cache_size "32k",realpath_cache_ttl "7200" , But do you suggest if we use compilation along with these setting is more beneficial.
I know there is no in built way to exclude a particular module but do we have any custom way to do this ?

Comment: I don't like the compiler, therefore I have no idea. But as I said. My understanding of the situation is, that the compiler just solves the problem of the lookup of the file. If you just have a cache to look it up, it solves the problem and if you don't need to look it up in the include path (as @PaulHachmang said: http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-class-path-cache.html) You don't need the compiler.

Comment: I know what I am asking is not related at all to original question but can the solution mentioned at reference link is beneficial for us , if we are using Magento FPC and memcache

Answer (score 0):

you can go to `/admin/system_config/edit/section/advanced/` in magento backend and disable the module.

Comment: He's talking about Compilation inside of magento not usage: https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21115376-What-is-Magento-s-Compilation-feature- and suppressing the output of a module is NOT disabling it.

Comment: @Anusha : Thanks for quick response but I don't want to disable module output , instead just want to exclude its files from compilation